# Multiplication table doesn't work when I specify a certain number of columns

Tags: javascript, arrays

I don't understand why the HTML table doesn't get built when I specify less columns than rows.

```
var table2 = Array(10);
for (var i = 0; i < table2.length; i++) {

// If I change Array(5) to something like Array(10) it doesn't work
table2[i] = Array(5);
}


var code = "<table cellpadding=\"15\" cellspacing=\"0\"><tr>"

for (row = 1; row <= table2.length; row++) {
  for (col = 1; col <= table2[col].length; col++) {
    code += "<td>" + col * row + "</td>";
  }
code += "</tr>";
};

document.getElementById('fart').innerHTML = code;
```

Link:  https://jsfiddle.net/pz4p9nff/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following corrections in your code will fix the problem you were facing.

```
var table2 = Array(10); //Init the amount of rows in your table
var code = "<table cellpadding=\"15\" cellspacing=\"0\">";

//Don't forget: arrays are zero based. Starting at 1 will skip row with index 0
for (row = 0; row < table2.length; row++){

    //Initialize each row with a fixed amount of columns... 
  //no need to do this in a seperate loop
    table2[row] = Array(5); 
  //Open each row properly
  code += "<tr>"; 

  //Loop the columns of each row
  for (col = 0; col < table2[row].length; col++){
    code += "<td>" + col*row + "</td>";
  }

  code += "</tr>";
};

code += "</table>"; //Close your table properly

document.getElementById('fart').innerHTML = code;
```

Comment: thanks for the comments explaining.   I'm still not sure why <= didn't work though.

Answer (score 1):

try this

```
var code = "<table cellpadding=\"15\" cellspacing=\"0\">"

for (row = 1; row <= 10; row++) {
    code += '<tr>';
    for (col = 1; col <= 5; col++) {
        code += "<td>" + col * row + "</td>";
    }
    code += "</tr>";
};

document.getElementById('fart').innerHTML = code;
```

Comment: duh, much simpler :)   Just started learning javascript, I was trying to play around with an example and didn't realize I could disregard all that stuff.  thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You have to correct you code as follows;

```js
var table2 = Array(10);
for (var i = 0; i < table2.length; i++){ 

// If I change Array(5) to something like Array(10) it doesn't work
 table2[i] = Array(10)
}
  

var code = "<table cellpadding=\"15\" cellspacing=\"0\"><tr>"

for (row = 1; row < table2.length; row++){ // !!! use < not <=
    for (col = 1; col < table2[row].length; col++){ // !!! use < not <= and table2[row]
      code += "<td>" + col*row + "</td>";
    }
  code += "</tr>";
  };
 
document.getElementById('fart').innerHTML = code;
```

```html
<div id ="fart">

</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Update your column interation loop as follows.

```
for (col =0; col < table2[row].length; col++) {
  code += "<td>" + col * row + "</td>";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to remove `<tr>` tag when you are initializing `code`

```
var code = "<table cellpadding=\"15\" cellspacing=\"0\">"
```

For every `row` a new `<tr>` tag should be appended.
The limit of inner `for` loop for `col` should be `table2.[row-1].length`. Since you are using `row` as a value variable and not index, it's value therefore starts from 1 but indexes usually start from 0.

```
for (row = 1; row <= table2.length; row++){
    code += "<tr>";
    for (col = 1; col <= table2[row-1].length; col++){
        code += "<td>" + col * row + "</td>";
    }
code += "</tr>";
};
```

You also need to close the `</table>` tag.

```
code+="</table>";
```

Updated https://jsfiddle.net/pz4p9nff/4/